# rails keeps repeating http requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, http

i have a rails server that's sending an http request in a controller to a node api on a different instance.

```
def send_to_node
    uri = URI.parse("http://www.example.com")

    http = Net::HTTP::new(uri.host, uri.port)
    node_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)

    node_request.set_form_data(params)

    node_response = http.request(node_request)
end
```

the response is successful. yet rails keeps sending the http request. like 7+ times. is there something i need to do to make sure rails doesn't repeat the request over and over again?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us code, where and how do you call this method?